# алгоритм Тайного Санты (SSA - Secret Santa Algorithm)

Tags: java

Готовлю новогоднюю вечеринку с друзьями, решили сыграть в тайного санту. Но до нового года не встречаемся, поэтому жеребьевка удаленно. Захотелось поиграться с кодом, вышел вот такой:

[Secret Santa Algorithm](http://rextester.com/live/PJNJK83149)

Цель - рандомно раскидать кто кому дарит подарок, так, чтобы не вышло ситуации, что человек дарит самому себе)

Смущает наличие костыля

```
if (j + 1 == guests.get(j))
```

Как думаете, что можно улучшить? 
Ожидается лаконичный, простой, не зависающий на большом количестве участников, выполняющий свою задачу алгоритм.

```
import java.util.*; 

class Rextester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int GUESTS_NUMBER = 10;
        List<Integer> guests = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < GUESTS_NUMBER;) {
            guests.add(++i);
        }
        boolean shuffled = false;
        outer:
        while (!shuffled) {
            Collections.shuffle(guests);
            shuffled = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < guests.size(); j++) {
                if (j + 1 == guests.get(j)) {
                    shuffled = false;
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < guests.size(); j++)
            System.out.println(j + 1 + " gives a gift to -> " + guests.get(j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А почему бы не сделать так?

1. Перенумеровать участников, пусть их `n`.
2. Сгенерировать коллекцию `{ 1, 2, ..., n }` и перетасовать её (`Collections.shuffle`)
3. Участник в первым номером в полученной коллекции делает подарок второму участнику в коллекции, второй — третьему, третий — четвёртому, ..., последний — первому.

Алгоритм генерирует просто цикл длины `n`. Особенность — никогда не будут сгенерированы несколько коротких циклов, всегда только один длинный.

Comment: Если можно уточнить, а в чем недостаток недостатка?

Comment: @Kromster: Ну, генерируются не все подходящие перестановки, а только часть.

Comment: А что такое "не все подходящие перестановки, а только часть"?

Comment: @Kromster: Ну допустим у нас 4 участника. Алгоритм никогда не скажет «пусть первый дарит второму, второй первому, третий четвёртому, а четвёртый третьему». Потому что он всегда генерирует длинный цикл.

Comment: Окей, так все же, в чем недостаток этого недостатка для "Секретного Санты"?

Comment: @Kromster: Этого я не знаю. Я честно рассказал Санте об особенностях решения, а вот считать эту особенность недостатком или нет — решать не мне.

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем алгоритме можно в цикле сделать проверку, если дарим самому себе, меняемся со следующим в очереди, если последний то с первым. 
Вот мой вариант:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int SANTA_NUMBERS = 10;

        List<Integer> santaList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < SANTA_NUMBERS; ) {
            santaList.add(++i);
        }

        List<Integer> guests = new ArrayList<>(santaList);
        Collections.shuffle(guests);

        //в этом цикле проверяем
        for (int i = 0; i < santaList.size(); i++) {
            if (santaList.get(i) == guests.get(i)) {
                if (i + 1 < santaList.size()){
                    Integer receiver = guests.get(i + 1);
                    guests.set(i + 1, guests.get(i));
                    guests.set(i , receiver);
                }else {
                    Integer receiver = guests.get(1);
                    guests.set(1, guests.get(i));
                    guests.set(i , receiver);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < santaList.size(); j++)
            System.out.println(santaList.get(j) + " gives a gift to -> " + guests.get(j));

    }
}
```